# What is a code to create a sub-folder in each folder and then move all the files and folders into that sub-folder?

Tags: powershell

I am organizing all the documents for our customers and the structure should be like this: `Customer Service\Customer\"Customer's Name"\Quotation`.

So far I managed to create the "Quotation" folder in each customer's folder.

```
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\Customer Service\Customer' -Directory)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ($folder.FullName + "\Quotes")
}
```

I have created the Quotes sub-folder in all the customer's folders. Now, I need to move all the files and folders from the customer's folder into its Quotes sub-folder. I would like to do it within one script ideally. Though, anything will be great as there are like hundreds of customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the code for creating the subfolder, all that's left to do is move the folder content to the new subfolder.

```
$dir    = 'C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\Customer Service\Customer'
$quotes = 'Quotes'

foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem $dir -Directory)) {
    $newdir = Join-Path $folder.FullName $quotes
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $newdir | Out-Null
    Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -Exclude $quotes |
        Move-Item -Destination $newdir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\Customer Service\Customer' -Directory))
{
        $files = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName
        $newfolder = new-item -ItemType directory -Path ($folder.fullname+"\Quotes")
        $files | Move-Item -Destination $newfolder.FullName
}
```

You can get a list of all files in a folder before creating the "Quotes" folder.

Comment: Works great! Next time I'll use it straightaway.